# npm install returns errors

Tags: node.js, npm

when I run npm install I get the following errors.

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT, open '/Users/IBricchi/package.json'
npm WARN generator-steroids@1.0.21 requires a peer of yo@1.8.1 || >=1.8.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib-clean@1.0.0 requires a peer of grunt@>= 0.4.5 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib-coffee@1.0.0 requires a peer of grunt@>= 0.4.5 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib-concat@1.0.1 requires a peer of grunt@>=0.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-contrib-sass@1.0.0 requires a peer of grunt@>=0.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-extend-config@0.9.5 requires a peer of grunt@>=0.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN IBricchi No description
npm WARN IBricchi No repository field.
npm WARN IBricchi No README data
npm WARN IBricchi No license field.
```

I've tried looking for answers online, but everything I've tried has done nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like package.json was not found by npm in `/Users/IBricchi/package.json`. Probably you are running npm install from your home directory by mistake. You should run `npm install` from your project root directory.